# Histogram with rolling window (Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rolling-computation

I am trying to create a histogram for each rolling window across a DataFrame. The rolling function in Python (df.WaveData.rolling(14).mean()) can be used for calculating sum or average, but how can we use it to plot histogram for data in each window?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-10, 10, 1000)
y = np.sin(x)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()


df = pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['WaveData'])
print(df)
print(df.WaveData.rolling(14).mean())

**Ideal**:
    for data in window:
        histogram(data_in_window)
        n, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=25)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import pandas as pd

# generate random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,size=(1000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

window_size = 100
for i in range(len(df.A.values)):
    window = df.A.values[i:i+window_size]
    n, bins, patches = plt.hist(window, 25)
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks @sehan2! Is there a way to find "n" and "bins" without the physical plot? Can we suppress the plot?

Comment: Sure you can. Take a look at np.histogram https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html